# How do I remove duplicate rows in MySQL using PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I have a database called 'master_database' and a table called 'info'

In the 'info' table I have multiple records and I need the 'email' field to not contain any duplicates but currently it does. What SQL command can I run to remove these duplicates?

Comment: Try `distinct` for email

Comment: So this will allow me to find the unique but how do I remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can know the rows that are repeated by using this:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(email) FROM info GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(email) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM master_database.info WHERE info.ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(info.ID) FROM master_database.info GROUP BY info.email HAVING COUNT(info.email) > 1)
```

This assumes you have a unique ID in the table where the higher the number the later the record, if you have a last_edited timestamp it might be better to use the MAX of that.

PLEASE TEST FIRST! Run the following to test:

```
SELECT * FROM master_database.info WHERE info.ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(info.ID) FROM master_database.info GROUP BY info.email HAVING COUNT(info.email) > 1)
```

These values will be deleted.

Comment: That will delete the rows with non-repeated emails also.

Comment: Sorry missed out a HAVING COUNT > 1

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have a unique field at all (ie the rows are really duplicates, the following methods will work):

Go to relevant table.
Create select query to select only the relevant duplicate row pairs.
Amend query to delete but add limit like:
DELETE FROM `[table name]` WHERE `[fieldname]`LIKE '[value]' AND `[fieldname]`LIKE '[value]' LIMIT 1
simulate to check effect before using query to delete one of a duplicate pair or repeat usage if there are more than a pair of duplicates

or

Go to relevant table.
Create select query to select only the relevant rows.
Copy query for later pasting.
Export button at the bottom of the query results will export just the query results.
Paste query back but amend it to delete those rows.
Copy export insert query for one of the duplicate rows to reinsert without the duplicate.

Comment: What if a table contains a lot of rows and doing such changes manually will take a lot of time?

Comment: Then it would be worth adding a unique field!

Comment: Bad things may happen and it's important to fix the consequences fastly with one values independent query

Comment: Oleksandr Savchenko your comment yesterday is unintelligible.