# How to delete a duplicate rows in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql

[image]

How to delete a duplicate rows in phpmyadmin?

Comment: What do you determine to be a duplicate here? Also, phpmyadmin is merely the client. You are looking for a `DELETE FROM` statement to run against the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove duplicate rows in MySQL using PHPMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946751/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql-using-phpmyadmin)